# How to save a function containing parameters into an RDS file?

Tags: r, function, save

Suppose that after some calculations I obtain a (floating) number, stored in the variable `a`, for example

```
a <- sqrt(2)
```

Now, I want to define a function that uses that parameter, for example:

```
myfunction <- function(x){x-a}
```

How can I save `myfunction` into an RDS file, in such a way that it can be loaded and used *in a new R session*, where the variable `a` is not defined?

Or from a different perspective: How to define the function, but substituting for `a` its actual numerical value in the function definition? That is, I'd like R to actually define the function

```
myfunction <- function(x){x - 2.1415.....}
```

where the actual value of `a` has been substituted in the definition.

Simply trying `saveRDS(myfunction, 'myfunction.rds')` does not work: if I start a new R session and do

```
myfunction <- readRDS('myfunction.rds')
myfunction(1)
```

then R complains that `a` is not defined.

Please note that I'm here giving a minimal working example of the problem. Obviously, in the case above I could just define `myfunction <- function(x){x-sqrt(2)}` and save that in an RDS file; it could be loaded in a new session and used without problems.

However, in my case I have many parameters like `a`, not just one, obtained from long calculations. I'm not interested in saving their values, I only want to save the function that uses them in its definition, and be able to use that function in a new R session.

Comment: I can't see `a` defined anywhere, this has nothing to do with `saveRDS`. If you define `a` it will work. You can define a default in `function(x, a=0)` or whatsoever.

Comment: `a` is the result of a long calculation, and I only need its value in the definition of a function. In my actual problem I don't have just one parameter; I have several, and it's not practical to save them all and reload them all and redefine all functions in a new R session.

Comment: I don't get what you mean when you say you don't want to save the parameters' values, but you want them accessible for use in the function you save. So where would the parameters be coming from? You wouldn't want to just save a list of the parameters, and read it back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RDS file won't save the global environment, but if you create a closure, it will preserve the values in that environment. One such way to do what would be

```
myfunction <- {function(a) function(x){x-a}}(a)
```

And then you can call this function like a regular function

```
myfunction(1)
```